# display a child view of frame layout at the front

Tags: android, view, android-framelayout

I want to change the view layer of a `FrameLayout`, and I try to call `bringToFront()` method. It does not work. Then, I tried to `setVisibility(View.GONE)` and `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.  Again, it does not work.

In fact, both of that method can change the top layer just once. For the second time, they all failed.

How can I do it?

```
private void next(){
    if(currentPage < MAX_INDEX){
        currentPage++;
        //indicator[currentPage].bringToFront();
        for(int i=0; i < MAX_INDEX; ++i){
            indicator[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        Log.d("current page:", "current page = " + currentPage);
        indicator[currentPage].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        SetupActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**
`removeAllViews()` and then `addView()` works for me. 
Anyone who d like to explain why I cant use `bringToFront()` and `setVisibility()` method, will be appreciated!

Comment: post ur code which u r trying

Comment: indicator is your view which you want to change.. what is parent layout of it? rather than hididng & showing., remove all views from its parent & add indicator[currentPage]. it may helps u

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, the indicator is the view I want to change. The parent of indicator is a `framelayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then try this code...

```
private void next(){
    if(currentPage < MAX_INDEX){
        currentPage++;
        //indicator[currentPage].bringToFront();

        framelayout.removeAllViews();

        Log.d("current page:", "current page = " + currentPage);
        framelayout.addView(indicator[currentPage]);
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        SetupActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after you have called  bringToFront(),another two method: requestLayout() and invalidate() should be called on the view's parent to force the parent to redraw;

you can refer this below
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()

Comment: You should elaborate on the information from the article.